# Enterprise Architect 9: Add Note to Connector

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I want to add notes to connectors in an Enterprise Architect diagram programmatically.
So far I only managed to add notes to elements with the following code:

```
 foreach (EA.Element element in Package.Elements)
            {
                foreach (EA.Connector conn in element.Connectors)
                {
                            EA.Element newNote = Package.Elements.AddNew("MyNote", "Note");
                            newNote.Notes = "Some string";
                            newNote.Update();

                            //position calculation is left out here
                            EA.DiagramObject k = diagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew(position, "");
                            k.ElementID = newNote.ElementID;
                            k.Sequence = 9;
                            k.Update();

                            EA.Connector newConn = newNote.Connectors.AddNew("NewLink", "NoteLink");
                            newConn.SupplierID = conn.SupplierID;
                            newConn.Update();

                            EA.DiagramLink newLink = diagram.DiagramLinks.AddNew("newLink", "NoteLink");
                            newLink.ConnectorID = newConn.ConnectorID;
                            newLink.Update();
```

The image maybe makes it more clear what I actually want:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3536/6bkijpg2_png.htm

My question is: How do I get the note attached to the connector? I assume I have to change this line "newConn.SupplierID = conn.SupplierID;", but "newConn.SupplierID = conn.ConnectorID" causes an exception.
I would be very happy if someone could help me!

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EA handles note links to connectors very differently from note links to elements.

Connectors always run between two elements. In your example, there are four elements (two of type `Activity` named O1 and O2, and two of type `Note`; these are usually nameless) and three connectors (O1 - O2, "This is what I have" - O2, and one from O1 running off the edge of the image).

The thing that looks like a connector from "This is what I want" to the O1 - O2 connector is not, in fact, a connector at all -- it just looks like one. In the GUI, the link to a connector is unresponsive and you can't bring up a properties dialog for it. This is why.

The fact that the note is linked to the connector is stored in the note element itself, in the `MiscData` collection. What you need to do is add the string `idref=<connector_id>;` to `MiscData(3)`. You may also need to set the `Note`'s `Subtype` field to 1.

However, `MiscData` is read-only so you'll have to go into the database and update `t_object` (where elements are stored) directly. `MiscData` in the API corresponds to `PDATA1` etc in the table. Note that the indices differ by one, so `MiscData(0)` corresponds to `PDATA1`, etc.

You will also need to use the undocumented `Repository.Execute()` since `Repository.SQLQuery()` only allows `select` statements.

So the following should work:

```
foreach (EA.Connector conn in element.Connectors) {
    EA.Element newNote = Package.Elements.AddNew("MyNote", "Note");
    newNote.Subtype = 1;
    newNote.Notes = "Some string";
    newNote.Update();
    repository.Execute("update t_object set PDATA4='idref=" + conn.ConnectorID + ";' " +
      where Object_ID=" + newNote.ElementID);

    //position calculation is left out here
    EA.DiagramObject k = diagram.DiagramObjects.AddNew(position, "");
    k.ElementID = newNote.ElementID;
    k.Sequence = 9;
    k.Update();
}
```

You may need to set the element subtype after the database update, I'm not sure.

`Element.Subtype` values are undocumented in the API, as are the contents of `Element.MiscData`, so this solution isn't future-proof (but it's very unlikely EA will ever change the way it handles these things).

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! It helps me to understand the connections of notes to connectors.
Now I run in another problem: 
    newNote.MiscData(3) = "idref=" + conn.ConnectorID + ";";
does not work, because MiscData is not a method. And newNote.MiscData[3] is read-only. How to set that value properly?

Comment: I found a solution for this problem: We have to set PDATA4 via SQL, which corresponds to MiscData[3] in the API. (Reference: https://leanpub.com/InsideEA/read).
This line does the job: Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_object SET PDATA4 = \"idref1=" + conn.ConnectorID + ";\" WHERE Object_ID = " + newNote.ElementID);
Afterwards the diagram needs to be updated to make the effects of the SQL statement visible.

Comment: You'll need to manipulate the underlying database table directly. I've updated the code sample accordingly.