# How to find a Notelink, in EA automation, that links a Note to a Connector (and note to an Element)

Tags: javascript, automation, enterprise-architect, supplier

I have an Enterprise Architect diagram with a Note linked (link L2) to a Connector (link L1). Using Automation API :

- myDiagram.diagramLinks actually contains L1, any link to an Element, **but definitively not** L2 which links to a connector
- the same, myNote.Connectors provides its connectors to Elements, but not to L1...

  1. How can I process ? Forced to use an SQLQuery ?
  2. I also wonder, once I'll have find L1, how I can determine weither L1.SupplierId is an Element or a Connector ?
     Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into that and it appears the linked element has a value in `t.object.PDATA4` (which equals `EAElement.MiscData(3)`) being

```
idref=<connId>;
```

where `<connId>` is the connector ID which it's linked to. There are as many semicolon separated entries as there as links to connectors.

Here's my setting:

[image]

two associations linked to a note. `t_connector` has two entries with IDs 1 and 2:

[image]

And now as you can see `t_object` looks like this:

[image]

The note (which is linked to the associations) has `PDATA` with references to the association IDs 1 and 2.

While you can read MiscData through the API it is (IIRC) r/o. In those cases I just fall back to `Repository.Execute` to run any `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: This is also documented in my Inside EA book on p 10.

Comment: Thanks for this response, which confirms what I found since my post on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826184/enterprise-architect-9-add-note-to-connector. In addition, once the Repository.Execute() done, it is recommanded to reload the diagram, so that it takes this update in account, before parsing this diagram.

Comment: Yes, using Execute bypasses the API so reloading diagrams (and packages) is needed. Not sure having seen it, but the API might also miss to update things in certain circumstances. I got used to such thing and test any automation for side effects and how to get around them.